# Virtual Penetration Test Lab - Figuring Out Its Market Size

Tags: malware, penetration-test, sandbox

Is there any reliable data available based on which the Global Market Size of Virtual Pen Testing Labs ( or Cyber Ranges ) can be ascertained ?

If NOT , is it possible to **calculate** it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The market for a penetration testing lab is probably a tiny subset of the market for penetration testing services and an even tinier subset of the market for information security. I'd encourage you to do your own investigation by reaching out to potential prospects, but a resource which may be of use is the Delling Institute. See: http://www.dellingadvisory.com/blog/2013/4/29/extrapolating-the-us-penetration-testing-market-size